# Hamiltonian paths in simple undirected subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory, prime-numbers, hamiltonian-path

I have an infinite sequence of simple connected undirected self-adjacency-free graphs $g_{n}$ for $n\ge3$, with the properties that $g_n$ has exactly $n$ vertices and also contains $g_{n-1}$ as a subgraph i.e. has one extra node, $V$, compared to $g_{n-1}$. The degree of $V$ is non-strictly increasing with $n$, but which existing vertices those new edges connect to is unpredictable - more specifically, an edge exists between vertices $i,j$ when $i+j$ is prime.

Is there anything I can say about whether these graphs contain Hamiltonian paths, given earlier ones do? Ideally, I would like to somehow prove that if a path exists for some value of $n$, this implies that a path also exists for all greater values, but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

I can see from how the degree of $V$ works that if I can somehow prove that $V$ having "enough" edges guarentees that an existing path can be extended to $n$ nodes from $n-1$, that solves my problem. I can also see that if I can prove $V$ is a neighbour to two nodes that are neighbours of each other, I can extend the path that way, but don't know how to prove that either.

Comment: Well, you're not going to have any new vertex be adjacent to both endpoints of the existing edge, because prime numbers don't work that way. (There are no pairs $i,j$ with $i+j=2$, so all edges link an odd vertex to an even vertex.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov I'm not sure if I've been misunderstood, but I mean "adjacent" in terms of graph edges, i.e. a pair of existing vertices where $i+j, i+V, j+V$ are all prime. In that context, I'm not sure where the difference of two comes from

Comment: $2$ is a prime, but it's the only even prime, and it doesn't correspond to any edges. If $i+V$ and $j+V$ are prime, then they're both odd, so $(i+V)+(j+V) = i+j+2V$ is even, so $i+j$ is even, therefore $i+j$ is not prime. So if there is an edge between $i$ and $V$, and an edge between $j$ and $V$, then there cannot be an edge between $i$ and $j$.